# Opening PDF on fancybox returns plugin error

Tags: jquery, pdf, fancybox-2

I am trying to open a pdf on fancybox like this:

```
$('.label').live("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = '<?php echo base_url()."requisitions/getLabel/" ?>' + $(this).attr('data-id') + "/" +$(this).attr('data-no'); 
    $.fancybox.open({
        href: href,
        type: 'iframe',
        autoSize: false,
        content: '<embed src = "'+href+'#nameddest=self&page=1&view=FitH, 0&zoom=80,0,0" type="application/pdf" height="99%" width="100%" />', 
        beforeClose: function(){
            $('.fancybox-inner').unwrap();
        },
        helpers:{
            overlay:{
                opacity:0.3
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
})
```

I have links on a Datatable with the class `.label`.

It is from this that the href is generated upon clicking.

While the fancybox pops up, the pdf does not show. It outputs a -

`A plugin is needed to generate this content.` message on Firefox.

On Chrome, a grey fancybox iframe is rendered. Right clicking on the fancybox popup

, a `Save as` option exists which actually saves the correct pdf.

I just want to show the pdf inline inside fancybox.

How do i do this with fancybox or otherwise,

Thanks.

Comment: does Firefox has adobe reader plugin installed? yeah, you need one. Go to "tools"-->"add-ons" and then "plugins" tab. You should have something like "Adobe Acrobat 10.1.7.27
Adobe PDF Plug-in For Firefox and Netscape 10.1.7". BTW, you don't need to use `.live()` if using jQuery 1.7+ use `.on()` instead

Comment: NB:I'm on a linux machine, At Add-ons i dont have have the Adobe Plugin, however installing the plugin from a script it i get notice that the plugin is already installed. On using `.live()` vs '.on()' what would be the advantage?

Comment: Still I get the error.